# How do I manually choose lat and long in Android emulator instead of choosing the point on map,

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-location

I get the image below when trying to set location, how can change it to so I can add it manulaly.

[image: screenshot]

Instead I'm looking to have the 2nd picture as my options to set location.

[image: screenshot]

If anyone can help, please?

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @hata thank you for the edit

Answer (score 0):

There's an "IMPORT GPX/KML" button if that helps. Write a point in a file and upload it. Or a route if that's what you're after.

[image]